# How to JSON decode with \\n in php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON structure as below

```
 $json = '{"Number1":"{\"answerPhrase\":\"\\nTEXT,\\nTEXT 
TEXT\\n\",\"dateUpdatedInMillisecond\":1234}"}';
```

When trying to extract the text and numbers I can do the first step and it works but the nested JSON has `\\n` and it does not give the text as output

The PHP code is as below

```
$result = json_decode($json);
print_r($result);
echo "<br>";
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.$value;
    echo "<br>";
    $result_nest = json_decode($value);
    echo  $result_nest->answerPhrase;
    echo "<br>";
```

Why can I not get the text in answerphrase? It works when the text does not have `\\n`

Comment: I get *"Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"* when trying to `json_decode` that string

Comment: Should I just replace all \\n from the variable?

Comment: try this 
echo "<pre>";print_r(json_decode($json, true));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below one. You can replace the \n with some other characters. If you want to display enter in browser then you can replace \n with 
. Please try the below code and let me know if it worked for you.

```
<?php
$json = '{"Number1":"{\"answerPhrase\":\"\\nTEXT,\\nTEXT TEXT\\n\",\"dateUpdatedInMillisecond\":1234}"}';

$result = json_decode($json);
print_r($result);
echo "\n";
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.$value;
    echo "<br>";
    $value = preg_replace("/\\n/", "___n___", $value);
    $result_nest = json_decode($value);
    $result_nest->answerPhrase = preg_replace("/___n___/", "\n", $result_nest->answerPhrase);

    echo  $result_nest->answerPhrase;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah this worked and the text appeared properly. Any idea why \\n would break in php?

Comment: Probably the json encoded value is not correct. Try `$json='{"Number1":{"answerPhrase":"\nTEXT,\nTEXT TEXT\n","dateUpdatedInMillisecond":"1234"}}';` or  `$a['answerPhrase']="\nTEXT,\nTEXT TEXT\n";
$a['dateUpdatedInMillisecond']="1234";
$b['Number1']=$a;
$json1=json_encode($b);
print_r($json1);
`

Comment: @ Abilash Amarasekaran : please flag this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to fix json before decode and then decode the sub json.
you could do second step in a loop

```
    function test2()
    {
        $string = '{"Number1":"{\"answerPhrase\":\"\\nTEXT,\\nTEXT
TEXT\\n\",\"dateUpdatedInMillisecond\":1234}"}';


        $json = $this->decodeComplexJson($string);
        $number = $json->Number1;
        //Put this in a loop if you want
        $decodedNumber = $this->decodeComplexJson($number);
        var_dump($decodedNumber);
        echo $decodedNumber->answerPhrase;

    }

    function decodeComplexJson($string) { # list from www.json.org: (\b backspace, \f formfeed)
        $string = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $string);
        $json = utf8_encode($string);
        $json = json_decode($json);
        return $json;
    }
```

Comment: I think I saw that code elsewhere. Should this be done all the time with json decode?

Comment: nope. if json is without special characters no need to do this